# No sound after installation on RaspberryPi

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have RaspPi 1B+. Today I did a fresh install of Debian and I have no sound on the jack.

In Audio Device Setting in GUI the system shows bcm2835 ALSA as default. I installed Rhythmbox and the mp3 file should be fine.

I have a screen connected via HDMI.

What can be wrong? How can I check what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it following the steps in [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md). I chose the `raspi-config` way, ie.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then:

> Select Option 8 `Advanced Options` and press `Enter`, then select
>   Option A6: `Audio` and press `Enter`:

And:

> Now you are presented with the two modes explained above as an
>   alternative to the default `Auto` option. Select a mode, press `Enter` and
>   press the right arrow key to exit the options list, then select `Finish`
>   to exit the configuration tool.

Now restarted and it works.